# Class object not working inside ob_start callback

Tags: php

I don't know why, but this code worked for me a month ago... maybe I upgraded the php but can't remember. Tried this with PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.6

Why is it not possible to use a class object inside the callback of a ob_start function?

```
<?php
$f=new stdClass();
$f->title="awesome Title";

function callback($buffer) 
{
    global $f;
    $buffer=str_replace("###TITLE###", $f->title, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
ob_start("callback");
?>

This is the ###TITLE###
```

Output is:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/qxxx/Sites/test/test.php on line 8
This is the
```

should be:

> This is the awesome Title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the output buffer is being implicitly flushed by the termination of the script.

At this point PHP has already destroyed unreferenced variables, so when it comes to execute your callback function, the variable `$f` does not exist in the global scope.

You can solve this by explicitly flushing the buffer before shutdown starts destroying objects, by placing the following line somewhere in your script.

`register_shutdown_function('ob_end_flush');`

**Edit:**

I'd like to add that even though this is currently the accepted answer that explains the *"why"*, the solution provided here does not address the root cause of the issue; the fact that `global` is being used.

Many people will tell you that `global` is evil, without giving a reason why. Here you can see one of the reasons.

The answer provided by **Jack** gives a more "best practice" solution (using closures to maintain the variable reference), and should be considered as the proper way to avoid using `global` in new codebases.

Comment: Indeed, to elaborate a bit: an important part of that is _"unreferenced variables"_ are destroyed, referenced ones aren't. A fine example why `global`'s tend to make code harder, and proper passing of references & arguments is preferred.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this has been outlined well by Leigh. Using a closure would work better in this case:

```
ob_start(function($b) use ($f) {
        return str_replace('###TITLE###', $f->title, $b);
});
```

This is because the closure will keep the reference to `$f` alive by the end of the script so that it won't get garbage collected before running the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

From the php manual page of `ob_start`, and [a bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40104) I learned that, since 5.2, all objects are destroyed @ob_start

> This function's behaviour  has been changed in php 5.2.0:

```
<?
    global $AP;
    $AP = new ap;
    ob_start("ob_end");
    function ob_end()
    {
        global $AP;
        $r = $AP->test();
        return $r;
    }
    class ap
    {
        function test()
        {
            return "debug";
        }
    }
?>
```

> In older versions it shows: "debug".
>   But latest php version causes error: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on > a non-object.
>   And this is not a bug: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40104

*from the man pages*

Comment: +1, thanks for the bug report reference, I didn't know it was actually changed behaviour (apart from the comments from the question author)

Comment: @Leigh: NP, had some trouble with an old piece of code I wrote a while back. I managed to get around it using a closure, though some people advice against it. Incidentally: do you know which is _better_, or is it just a matter of preference/habit? I can't help thinking it has more to do with people not _understanding_ how closures work, than with actual code-quality

Comment: I agree with you, it's not a bad habit to **understand** why you are doing something. Using a closure (IMHO) is not a workaround, it is the correct way to preserve the variable reference, and avoid using `global`. How can it be wrong to use a language feature the way it was intended.